# Isn't there a faster way to delete events from the Calendar on my iPhone/iPod-touch?

Tags: iphone, ipod-touch, calendar

Do I really have to:

1. Enter the event
2. Select the Edit button
3. Scroll down
4. Select "Delete Event" button
5. Confirm "Delete Event"

Isn't there a faster way to delete an event on my iPhone/iPod-touch?

Comment: I don't have the iPhone anymore. But didn't this work?: Hold for a second. Then drag to the garbage can that pops up.

Comment: @gentmatt I can drag, but looks like there is no garbage can or any place I can release it to delete.

Answer (score 1):

There is not a faster way to delete events in the Cal app.

in the iOS5 beta, you could quickly delete an event in the day view by holding and dragging up, this feature was removed from the full release. [There is a blog post I have dug up here](http://www.imore.com/2011/06/13/ios-5-feature-tap-hold-add-move-adjust-delete-calendar-event/)

---

my personal opinion on this is that it would be easy to delete an even when changing it to one hour earlier by draggin it up.